# Cross File Javascript Async Function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to have controller-view structure in my Vue project, and separate frontend display and frontend logic into two files. In the component, I would make a functional call to a controller method, and in the controller method, it will interact with backend API, but it seems like the async function is not working.

Here is the code in my Vue component:

```
import { authenticate } from '../controllers/userController'

function login() {
  if (email.value && password.value) {
    authenticate(email.value, password.value, remember.value).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  } else {
    // Input Validation Failed
  }
}
```

And here is the implementation of the `authenticate()`

```
async function authenticate(email, password, remember) {
  axios.post(APIURL + '/v1/login', { email, password }, {
    headers: { 'X-Access-Key': APIAccessKey, 'X-Key-Secret': APIKeySecret }
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    return {}
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    return {}
  })
}

export {
  authenticate
}
```

And this is what I see in the console:
[image]

As shown in the image, the response console log in the Vue Component returns undefined, and it is printed out before the response in the controller. It should have waited until the response is completed in the API call. So I am wondering what I did wrong, any help is appreciated.

Please ignore the 401 error, that error is intentionally introduced, the focus is that the `console.log(response)` should not be undefined, it should wait the response of the API call, and print out the API result

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also, the exact error message is being covered in your screenshot.

Comment: It looks like there are multiple problems, which one are you specifically asking about?  Somewhere (line 64 of `Login.vue`?  it's hard to tell from the image) there is code that's trying to read a property (which we can't see) from `undefined`.  Which you can't do, so your next step there would be to examine that code and either change it to handle an `undefined` value or trace why that value is `undefined` and correct the source of that value.  Aside from that, your `login` request appears to be a "bad request" according to the server, and you'll need to determine specifically why.

Comment: @David I edited the question with updates at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return your promise from `authenticate`:

```
// No need to mark `async` since `await` isn't used
function authenticate(email, password, remember) {
  // add `return`
  return axios.post(APIURL + '/v1/login', { email, password }, {
    headers: { 'X-Access-Key': APIAccessKey, 'X-Key-Secret': APIKeySecret }
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    return {}
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    return {}
  })
}
```

Otherwise, `authenticate(...).then` is the same as

```
authenticate();
Promise.resolve(undefined).then();
```